# No such file or directory even though there is a folder

Tags: macos, terminal

My terminal is saying this:

"no such file or directory". Even when I can see the folder named "Marcy" on my desktop.

Pls, help. It is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Right click  on the folder "Marcy" and then select get info. In "get info", the actual location of the folder is displayed near the top as shown below.

[image]

Another way to accomplish this is by using the terminal. From the terminal type:

```
locate filename
```

This should list the full path to the file and you can easily delete it by typing:

```
rm /path_to_file/filename
```

The "locate" command will list all occurrences of the file name so be sure to delete the one on your main disc drive and not one that may appear on a backup drive.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include how you could do this using the terminal.

Comment: I get this now:

Comment: azfars-MacBook-Pro:~ ausieebilal$ Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨ausieebilal⁩ ▸ ⁨Desktop⁩
-bash: Macintosh: command not found

Comment: open the terminal app and type  locate filename   it should work fine.

Comment: you may have a problem with you PATH variable. Try typing ./locate and see if that works?

Comment: try ytyping this command on your command line: export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Comment: azfars-MacBook-Pro:~ ausieebilal$